# Does the series $S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2x^2}{n^4+x^4}$ converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

does the above series uniformly converges? If it does, how to find the interval of x in which it uniformly converges?
$ {(n^2-x^2)}^2 \ge 0 \Rightarrow n^4 + x^4 - 2n^2x^2 \ge 0$

This gave me $\frac{n^2x^2}{n^4+x^4} \le 1/2$. So, I couldn't apply Weierstrass M-Test as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1/2)$ diverges. Couldn't proceed further. Please help.

Comment: I would change the title to call the series $S(x)$ - the series you've defined doesn't actually have a dependence on $n$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction

Comment: For $x=o(\sqrt{n})$, the series converges. Thus, you can try any $x = an^{1/2-\epsilon}$ and can prove convergence for any $\epsilon>0$. To see thus, see that $n^2x^2/(n^4+x^2)\le a^2/n^{1+2\epsilon}$.

Comment: @Vaneet why are you treating $x$ as if it has a dependence upon $n$?

Comment: Ap special case is $\epsilon=1/2$ where it does not depend on $n$. What I mean is that even if it is of the above form, it works.

Answer (score 4):

Note that for $x\in [-a,a]$ for any $a>0$, we have

$$\frac{n^2x^2}{n^4+x^4}\le \frac{a^2}{n^2}$$

and the Weierestrass M-Test guarantees that the series converges uniformly on any bounded interval.

Comment: Hi @Dr.MV thank you for the simple and clear solution.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure. Very pleased that this was useful.  -Mark

Answer (score 3):

If we have:

$$S_m(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m \frac{n^2x^2}{n^4+x^4},S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2x^2}{n^4+x^4}$$

then

$$\sup_\mathbb{R}\vert S_m(x)-S(x)\vert\ge\vert S_m(m+1)-S(m+1)\vert=\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{n^2(m+1)^2}{n^4+(m+1)^4}\ge\frac{(m+1)^2(m+1)^2}{(m+1)^4+(m+1)^4}=\frac{1}{2}$$

so $\vert\vert S_m-S\vert\vert_\infty$ does not converge to $0$, and hence our series does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

As noted in an earlier post, it does converge uniformly on bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi could you please explain further the first step, are you verifying the Cauchy principle of convergence?

Comment: Uniform convergence is equivalent to showing that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\vert S_m(x) - S(x) \vert \to 0$, and I'm showing here that it does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Thank you for the formal proof. I have understood it. However a small correction in the last step I think it is (m+1)^4 + (m+1)^4 is what you intended to write. How to get that denominator, I have understood the numerator part. Thanks once again.

Comment: Hi you have shown that sum of the series of positive terms( m+1 to infinity) is greater than its first term which is 1/2. Am i right in saying so?

Answer (score 3):

*This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment. It is just a curiosity.*

I worked this summation long time ago and identified that
$$S(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2x^2}{n^4+x^4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi  x}{4}\,\frac{\sin \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  x\right)-\sinh \left(\sqrt{2} \pi 
   x\right)}{\cos \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  x\right)-\cosh
   \left(\sqrt{2} \pi  x\right)}$$ which is defined for any value of $x$.